# Laravel Tests in custom directory - Getting error "the name is already in use"

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to build a application that uses laravel. There is a test directory and I use it for application testing.

But I have an service in app/MyApp/Service directory. Here is the directory structure.

```
app/MyApp/Service 
|-->Services 
|-->Interfaces 
|-->Test 
|------->OLSServiceTest.php
```

Here is OLSServiceTest.php content

```
<?php

namespace App\MyApp\Service\Test;

class OLSServiceTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testInfo()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function testLogin()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * Needs to be implemented by subclasses.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        // TODO: Implement createApplication() method.
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to run the test manually

```
$ vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit App\\MyApp\\Service\\Test\\OLSServiceTest
```

But getting this error :

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Cannot declare class App\MyApp\Service\Test\OLSServiceTest, because
>   the name is already in use
>
> Fatal error: Cannot declare class
>   App\MyApp\Service\Test\OLSServiceTest, because the name is already in
>   use in /var/www/app/MyApp/Service/Test/OLSServiceTest.php on line 29

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other class with the same name in to that namespace ? can you try with something diff name of the class ?

Comment: No way, When I change the name I'm getting the error with new name.

Comment: Have you tried to run tests with path instead of namespace ? vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit  app/MyApp/Service/Test/OLSServiceTest.php ?

Comment: Worked when I tried with path, than you very much @shivanshupatel

Comment: cool I have posted same thing it to the answer you can mark it as correct if it works :) good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to run test with wrong command. Try to use PHPUnit from Vendor bin directory I think it will solve your issue.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit app/MyApp/Service/Test/OLSServiceTest.php
```